# Same functions, but arrays not identical - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, convolution

I am trying to test my 2D Convolution function, to see if I get the same output as from scipy.signal.convolve2D function.

My code is this:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
def conv2D(f, g):
    # f is an image and is indexed by (v, w)
    # g is a filter kernel and is indexed by (s, t),
    #   it needs odd dimensions
    # h is the output image and is indexed by (x, y),
    #   it is not cropped
    if g.shape[0] % 2 != 1 or g.shape[1] % 2 != 1:
        raise ValueError("Only odd dimensions on filter supported")
    # smid and tmid are number of pixels between the center pixel
    # and the edge, ie for a 5x5 filter they will be 2.
    #
    # The output size is calculated by adding smid, tmid to each
    # side of the dimensions of the input image.
    vmax = f.shape[0]
    wmax = f.shape[1]
    smax = g.shape[0]
    tmax = g.shape[1]
    smid = smax // 2
    tmid = tmax // 2
    xmax = vmax + 2*smid
    ymax = wmax + 2*tmid
    # Allocate result image.
    h = np.zeros([xmax, ymax], dtype=f.dtype)
    # Do convolution
    for x in range(xmax):
        for y in range(ymax):
            # Calculate pixel value for h at (x,y). Sum one component
            # for each pixel (s, t) of the filter g.
            s_from = max(smid - x, -smid)
            s_to = min((xmax - x) - smid, smid + 1)
            t_from = max(tmid - y, -tmid)
            t_to = min((ymax - y) - tmid, tmid + 1)
            value = 0
            for s in range(s_from, s_to):
                for t in range(t_from, t_to):
                    v = x - smid + s
                    w = y - tmid + t
                    value += g[smid - s, tmid - t] * f[v, w]
            h[x, y] = value
    return h
```

The scipy function is this:

```
x = convolve2d(file, kernel, mode="full", boundary="fill", fillvalue=0)
```

My function uses 0 padding, and the input data (file) is always a float type array. The output matrix are 'result' for my function and 'x' for scipy's.

I tested the difference with 3 methods found on SO:

1. With 'np.array_equal()'

   ```
   np.array_equal(x, result)
   ```

I get the result as false.

2. With

   ```
   (x==result).all()
   ```

I get the result false as well.

3. I did this difference in matrices:

   ```
   dif = result - x

   print dif
   for i in dif:
       if i.any > 0:
           print i
   ```

It gets me printed the values, but I printed the basic matrix statistics as well, and the structure is identical:

```
Structure result
(dtype('float64'), 0.022222222222222223, 3.3333333333333335, (9L, 9L), 0.92592592592592593,)
Structure x
(dtype('float64'), 0.022222222222222223, 3.3333333333333335, (9L, 9L), 0.92592592592592593)
```

I tested this two with these:

```
file = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5),
                 (1,2,3,4,5),
                 (1,2,3,4,5),
                 (1,2,3,4,5),
                 (1,2,3,4,5)])

kernel = np.array([(1/45, 1/45, 1/45,1/45,1/45),
                  (1/45, 3/45, 3/45,3/45,1/45),
                  (1/45, 3/45, 5/45,3/45,1/45),
                  (1/45, 3/45, 3/45,3/45,1/45),
                  (1/45, 1/45, 1/45,1/45,1/45)])
```

Why are the results different if it processes with basically the same method?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html, there is a difference in what you see printed and what is actually in the array, iterate over end print the repr of each float

Comment: With Padraic's comment in mind: try using [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) instead of `numpy.array_equal`.

Comment: There's a difference between your two structures, a coma at the end. Couldn't this means that even though you have same data, you are actually storing them slightly differently ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I run 'repr()' for both the result, x and difference. The result and x are the same, but the dif hav values > 0 or < 0, although they are ^16 or ^17. How can I be sure that my function is running well?

Comment: @Evert Using 'numpy.allclose' gave method 1 true and method 2 false.

Comment: @Yann Sorry about that, it was only a '\n' for printing a newline, forgot to update de code in here.

Comment: `print(x==result).all()` returns True for me, as does `print(np.array_equal(x, result))`, what OS are you using?

Comment: Also my output is not the same as yours if the output in your question is from the two arrays file and kernel

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I re-run the code, and I always get False on 'print (x==result).all()'  for the data input as in my question. I am using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Is the output in your question from using the two arrays you have supplied? Can you add exactly how you are running the functions and what output you get for both x and result to pastebin?

Comment: Yes. I only tested that, so I can get the right help.

Comment: I don't get anything close to what you have in your question as output

Comment: The outputs (result and x) are the arrays returned by the functions. The input data I tested is file and kernel. I cannot post the arrays here, but I uploaded the output here: http://we.tl/BEnsR2IQae

Comment: I don't understand how you want to use `numpy.allclose` in your "method 2". It's not even meant for testing that, it's meant for actually comparing floating point numbers/arrays (which I've assumed is what you actually want). Note that `allclose`  has an `atol` keyword, which you may need to use when numbers in the array get close to zero.

Comment: I don't want to use a specified method. I only want to make sure that my function returns the same matrix as the 'scipy' one.